# How to stop amplification attacks BIND DNS?

Tags: domain-name-system, security, named-conf

I am having trouble determining what values I should set my rate-limit to.
The only example I have seen is this ...

```
    rate-limit {
            responses-per-second 5;
            window 5;
    };
```

... is that too tight? Can it cause problems for my clients?  This is
suppose to help defeat amplification attacks right?

Thanks!